# How can I query for new stored entities of a Session which are not yet saved to the database?

Tags: ravendb

Example:

```
var test = new Test();
test.Id = "theId";
Session.Store(test);
Session.Load<Test>("theId") // retrieves the object
Session.Query<Test>().Where(t => t.Id == "theId").ToList() // doesn't retrieve the object - This is where I need it
Session.SaveChanges();
Session.Query<Test>().Where(t => t.Id == "theId").ToList() // retrieves the object
```

I can query for my new object after SaveChanges() - which is too late for my scenario. How can I get RavenDB Session to consider local changes?

Comment: See related question: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/MGryTSESTS4

Comment: this goes a little against the philosophy of ravendb; however, even the second call may not retrieve the object (index > stale results); why do you need to take the newly saved object if you created it above?

Comment: @Embri I just provided some sample code so you could see what I need. In reality I coded multiple Steps-Classes which do their own business logic and manipulate the database on execution. Those steps can be executed on their own or in a particular order. For example I first want to execute Step 1 and then Step 2. Step 1 manipulates products and Step 2 needs to retrieve those manipulated products and not the old ones. It is just the way I designed this application

Comment: ok, but before you need to unterstand how works ravendb and if it fits for your needs, not after. Example, load is ACID, query is BASE

Comment: Yes, I should have done more research before jumping right into RavenDb. Thank you for pointing out ACID and BASE.